# Giving value using method

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I want to give a value to Morning (this is in an own class):

```
String morning;

void setMorning(String newMorning) {morning = newMorning;}
```

using (in the main):

```
System.out.println("Write a description ");
               = input.nextLine();
```

the object is:

```
Day saturday = new Day();
```

So the question is what do i put before the = input.nextLine(); ?

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is what do i put before the = input.nextLine(); ? Or is this even possible? Help?

If I understand you, you could use

```
System.out.println("Write a description ");
Day saturday = new Day();
saturday.setMorning(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: This is assuming setMorning is in the Day class.